# Cannot boot from Windows 7 disc

Tags: hard-drive, installation, operating-systems

I just installed a new hard drive on my computer after the old one crashed.  Now I cant get it to boot up.

I set the boot diectory to

1. Cdrom
2. Hard disk
3. Removable

And when I put the Windows 7 disc in the drive it says no booting system or something like that and then lists my sata drives

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 typically comes on DVD's. Do you have a DVDROM or CDROM?

Comment: my money is on this being the problem.

Comment: yes it is a dvd rom

Comment: So the BIOS IS picking up the DVDROM then? Have you used this DVD before? Are you able to boot from any other CD/DVD's with that DVDROM?

Comment: it wont boot from any of the dvds i have tried i used my windows 7 dvd no luck then i tried using the dvd tht came with the computer to reinstall windows xp nothing i took it back apart double checked my installation and i missed nothing .  i used this computer for 2 years until i got a nasty virus and decided to set it up on a new hard drive secure my system and then try to retrieve any info off the old hard drive but i just cannot get the thing to boot and i sure dont want to invest in another windows 7 system

Answer (score 0):

Either the Windows 7 boot DVD is incorrect, or your DVD reader is dead.

It should be easy enough to find out which.

Comment: ok so how would i find out which it is i mean my computer does nothing at all just boots up the dell symbol and runs dos

Comment: Has this DVD ever worked for you in the past? Has it worked on the specific machine you are trying it on?

Comment: Can you try this DVD on another computer? Do you have another boot DVD?

Comment: yeah it worked before i installed it prior to my computer crashing, got a nasty virus. i have no other computer or dvd drive to try it on but my dvd drive kicks on and off but i can hear it running but it just does not boot

Comment: The fact it is making a noise doesn't mean it's working.

Comment: ok well guess ill replace it and go from there even if its still working been wanting to install another one thansk for the help